# Неясность при создании собственной модели данных унаследованной от QAbstractListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Создаю свою модель унаследованную от QAbstactListModel, в нем есть поле
 QList list; в конструкторе параметром передаю ссылку на QList, переопределяю метод setData(), но только как компилятор понимает что данные из модели для представления QListView и QTableView должны браться из поля QListlist моего класса, ведь в коде не было model.setData(), а этот переопределенный метод вызывается при изменении данных в представлении для возможности редактирования данных в представлении. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: изучаю Qt по книге Макс Шлее Qt 5.3 профессиональное программирование на С++, вопрос касается 12 главы, раздел "Создание собственных моделей данных".

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно переопределить метод `Data`. Вообще, когда наследуете какие-либо классы из библиотеки Qt, читайте в документации главу "Subclassing". Там написано, что наследники класса `QAbstractListModel` должны переопределять методы `rowCount` и `data`. Метод `rowCount` может выглядеть так:

```
int QAbstractItemModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override 
{
     return list.size();
}
```

Метод `data` может выглядеть так:

```
QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    return QVariant(list.at(index.row));
}
```

Было бы неплохо также переопределить метод `headerData` для того, чтобы ваша таблица с помощью этого метода извлекала заголовки столбцов.

Comment: Да все верно, я просто все это опустил, вопрос просто не в этом, а в том как данные для представления берутся из поля QList list класса моей модели ведь метода setData() не было, да и он переопределен только для изменения елементов в представлениях.

Comment: @Dmitrii, в листе есть какие-то элементы? Объект вашего класса назначен моделью для таблицы? Если да, то они отобразятся в таблице. А метод setData предназначен для изменения существующих элементов, но не для добавления новых.

Comment: Да в листе есть елементы, код как в учебнике:

Comment: Я еще проекспериментировал добавить в мой класс другое поле QList<int> list2, практика показала что модель будет оперировать данными из первого проинициализированного конструктором поля(это так ??????), и сразу вопрос а какие еще контейнеры можно использовать для моей модели от QStandardListModel ?????????

Comment: @Dmitrii, можно использовать абсолютно любые контейнеры. Можно вообще обойтись без контейнеров.

Comment: @Dmitrii, если у вас всё ещё проблемы, обновите, пожалуйста, вопрос, так как я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите.